# Index is not scanning after made it unusable

Tags: oracle, indexing, fetch, sql-execution-plan

For existing table i have added the index to check the performance. Table has 1.5 million records. The existing cost is "58645". Once created the index the cost is reduced to "365". So that often time I have made the index as "unusable". Then I alter and rebuild the index to check. For yesterday known the index is being used by explain plan in oracle. But today when I unusable the index and rebuild, in explain plan the index scan was not working. But performance remains fast than older. I have dropped and created again. But still the issue is remaining. Fetching is fast. But the explain plan showing that the index is not being used and the cost is showing "58645". Am stuck with this.

Comment: For such tests you can better use `ALTER INDEX ... INVISIBLE;`, see [ALTER INDEX](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1012.htm#SQLRF52779)

Comment: the performance should be your criterion. but because of number of recordes fetchs by query the plan can change from index range scan to full table scan.

Comment: Try to look at actual execution plan in session trace, it can differ from *explain plan*.

Comment: What is "15 lac"?

Answer (score 0):

Many times when you create the new index or rebuild it from scratch it doesn't show up in explain plan and sometime is not used for a while as well. To correct the explain plan the stats should be gathered on index.

EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_INDEX_STATS should be used or use DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS with cascade option.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks of data are cached in the BUFFER_POOL, which will affect your results such that:

1. Run Query;
2. Change Index;
3. Run Query; - buffered data from 1 will skew the preformance
4. Flush buffer pool
5. Run Query - now you get a truer measure of how "fast" the query is.

Did you flush the buffer?

```
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH BUFFER_POOL;
```

Comment: woo Flushing buffer pool is not needed it is actually a bad idea will cause a lot of hard parses..

Comment: This is for testing - that is what the OP I think is trying to do, to compare the query performance.